# Making n-sided polygons in Blender 2.69

Tags: modeling

Is there anyway to create n-sided polygons in Blender without having to set the user preferences to 'enter edit mode' when adding a mesh. I'm asking this because there are times when I want add a cylinder mesh with n-gons on the top or to initialize a mesh previous to adding it to a scene.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes** This is possible.

For a cylinder:

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Add mesh > Cylinder*
2. Press <kbd>F6</kbd> and set the *Cap Fill Type* to *Ngon*.

If you are looking to do this from python:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(radius=1, depth=2, end_fill_type='NGON', view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(-2.06615, -0.413393, 3.45981), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))
```

Or have a look at the [bmesh api](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bmesh.html).

For doing this in the interface, usually one uses *Edit mode* (perhaps you could elaborate on why this doesn't work for you?). To create an ngon in edit mode, select the faces you wish to convert to a single face and press <kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: Either F6 or the **Redo panel** in the lower left corner of the 3D View sidebar should do the job.